# Running and displaying classes imported from other files in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am creating a piece of software for my organisation which I recently started, and I am using the Tkinter module in Python to create my software. The software is similar to how an operating system works, but it isn't an operating system, and it runs like a normal program on your desktop. In the software, there are numerous applications, like a word-processor (more on that later), a spreadsheet editor, etc.

The first application I am creating is a word processor called Wordee, and I've based it on a style that mirrors Microsoft Notepad. I want the user to click a button and the word-processor opens code from a class in another file in the same directory. This class is the code for the word processor.

I have written that code, but it always opens the word processor first and then when you close the word processor, the window that you should access the word processor from.

Here is the code which I am currently developing - everything that I have written was where I got up to when I noticed the problem:

```py
from tkinter import *
import time
import os
import wordProcessorExample as wPE

window = Tk()
window.title("Brainwave One")

def get_datetime():
    timeVariable = time.strftime("%I:%M %p, %A %d %B %Y")
    date_time.config(text=timeVariable)
    date_time.after(200,get_datetime)

def wordee():
    print(wPE.Wordee)
    

date_time = Label(window,font=("Calibri",15))
date_time.grid(row=0,column=0)

title = Label(window,text="Brainwave One",font=("Calibri",40))
title.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.05,anchor="center")

title = Label(window,text="From The Brainwave Incorporation",font=("Calibri",13))
title.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.083,anchor="center")

wordee = Button(window,text="Wordee",font=("Calibri",23),command=wordee)
wordee.place(relx=0.25,rely=0.1875,anchor="center")

get_datetime()

window.mainloop()
```

Here is the other file that I am accessing the class for the word processor from:

```py
import tkinter
import os   
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import *
from tkinter.filedialog import *
 
class Wordee:
 
    __root = Tk()
 
    # default window width and height
    __thisWidth = 300
    __thisHeight = 300
    __thisTextArea = Text(__root)
    __thisMenuBar = Menu(__root)
    __thisFileMenu = Menu(__thisMenuBar, tearoff=0)
    __thisEditMenu = Menu(__thisMenuBar, tearoff=0)
    __thisHelpMenu = Menu(__thisMenuBar, tearoff=0)
     
    # To add scrollbar
    __thisScrollBar = Scrollbar(__thisTextArea)    
    __file = None
 
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
 
        # Set icon
        try:
                self.__root.wm_iconbitmap("Wordee.ico")
        except:
                pass
 
        # Set window size (the default is 300x300)
 
        try:
            self.__thisWidth = kwargs['width']
        except KeyError:
            pass
 
        try:
            self.__thisHeight = kwargs['height']
        except KeyError:
            pass
 
        # Set the window text
        self.__root.title("Untitled - Wordee")
 
        # Center the window
        screenWidth = self.__root.winfo_screenwidth()
        screenHeight = self.__root.winfo_screenheight()
     
        # For left-align
        left = (screenWidth / 2) - (self.__thisWidth / 2)
         
        # For right-align
        top = (screenHeight / 2) - (self.__thisHeight /2)
         
        # For top and bottom
        self.__root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (self.__thisWidth,
                                              self.__thisHeight,
                                              left, top))
 
        # To make the textarea auto resizable
        self.__root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.__root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
 
        # Add controls (widget)
        self.__thisTextArea.grid(sticky = N + E + S + W)
         
        # To open new file
        self.__thisFileMenu.add_command(label="New",
                                        command=self.__newFile)   
         
        # To open a already existing file
        self.__thisFileMenu.add_command(label="Open",
                                        command=self.__openFile)
         
        # To save current file
        self.__thisFileMenu.add_command(label="Save",
                                        command=self.__saveFile)   
 
        # To create a line in the dialog       
        self.__thisFileMenu.add_separator()                                        
        self.__thisFileMenu.add_command(label="Exit",
                                        command=self.__quitApplication)
        self.__thisMenuBar.add_cascade(label="File",
                                       menu=self.__thisFileMenu)    
         
        # To give a feature of cut
        self.__thisEditMenu.add_command(label="Cut",
                                        command=self.__cut)            
     
        # to give a feature of copy   
        self.__thisEditMenu.add_command(label="Copy",
                                        command=self.__copy)        
         
        # To give a feature of paste
        self.__thisEditMenu.add_command(label="Paste",
                                        command=self.__paste)        
         
        # To give a feature of editing
        self.__thisMenuBar.add_cascade(label="Edit",
                                       menu=self.__thisEditMenu)    
         
        # To create a feature of description of the notepad
        self.__thisHelpMenu.add_command(label="About Wordee",
                                        command=self.__showAbout)
        self.__thisMenuBar.add_cascade(label="Help",
                                       menu=self.__thisHelpMenu)
 
        self.__root.config(menu=self.__thisMenuBar)
 
        self.__thisScrollBar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)                   
         
        # Scrollbar will adjust automatically according to the content       
        self.__thisScrollBar.config(command=self.__thisTextArea.yview)    
        self.__thisTextArea.config(yscrollcommand=self.__thisScrollBar.set)
     
         
    def __quitApplication(self):
        self.__root.destroy()
        # exit()
 
    def __showAbout(self):
        showinfo("Notepad","Mrinal Verma")
 
    def __openFile(self):
         
        self.__file = askopenfilename(defaultextension=".wde",
                                      filetypes=[("All Files","*.*"),
                                        ("Text Documents","*.wde")])
 
        if self.__file == "":
             
            # no file to open
            self.__file = None
        else:
             
            # Try to open the file
            # set the window title
            self.__root.title(os.path.basename(self.__file) + " - Wordee")
            self.__thisTextArea.delete(1.0,END)
 
            file = open(self.__file,"r")
 
            self.__thisTextArea.insert(1.0,file.read())
 
            file.close()
 
         
    def __newFile(self):
        self.__root.title("Untitled - Wordee")
        self.__file = None
        self.__thisTextArea.delete(1.0,END)
 
    def __saveFile(self):
 
        if self.__file == None:
            # Save as new file
            self.__file = asksaveasfilename(initialfile='Untitled.wde',
                                            defaultextension=".wde",
                                            filetypes=[("All Files","*.*"),
                                                ("Text Documents","*.wde")])
 
            if self.__file == "":
                self.__file = None
            else:
                 
                # Try to save the file
                file = open(self.__file,"w")
                file.write(self.__thisTextArea.get(1.0,END))
                file.close()
                 
                # Change the window title
                self.__root.title(os.path.basename(self.__file) + " - Wordee")
                 
             
        else:
            file = open(self.__file,"w")
            file.write(self.__thisTextArea.get(1.0,END))
            file.close()
 
    def __cut(self):
        self.__thisTextArea.event_generate("<<Cut>>")
 
    def __copy(self):
        self.__thisTextArea.event_generate("<<Copy>>")
 
    def __paste(self):
        self.__thisTextArea.event_generate("<<Paste>>")
 
    def run(self):
 
        # Run main application
        self.__root.mainloop()
 
 
 
 
# Run main application
Wordee = Wordee(width=600,height=400)
Wordee.run()
```

Comment: You need to move those lines before `__init__()` of class `Wordee` into `__init__()`.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: It means that from the line `__root = Tk()` to `__file = None`, those lines should be moved into beginning of `__init__()`.  And prefix each variable with `self.`.

Comment: Also the last three lines (from `# Run main application` to the end) should be removed.

Comment: @acw1668 I have done what you suggested, but the script doesn't recognise ```self.```, so if I prefix the variables with ```self.``` it won't recognise it. What should I do?